# Unauthorized message returned in node.js push GCM

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to push a notification to my android device from node.js through GCM.
I tried the below code to send the push but I receive unauthorized and null message when I executed node server.js(where server.js has the code). I just have the code to get registration id in the Client side(android app code). I have not implemented any code related to receiving through GCM receiver

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var message = new gcm.Message();
var sender = new gcm.Sender('AIzaSyDMSfDB4W8q1TaN2Wp4fOsGu6HSl4INzZo');
var registrationIds = [];

message.addData('title','Hello');
message.addData('message','How are you doing?');
message.addData('msgcnt','1');
message.collapseKey = 'demo';
message.delayWhileIdle = true;
message.timeToLive = 3;

// At least one token is required - each app will register a different token
registrationIds.push('APA91bG1uXE8MSGVGVlQG6OY_XtzHkUPFA5aj-fnCcr_8mZSpe6_-fM78e1cunoMYVLskIBVRXa1Rg9RL_jMsK-azLxmhjL1Sl8IUc7VCHtT0XR_pqMMxPQHN-MZyZmV017RS8OeVytbp0WT1kDzBouOoErlg2U_AXUuww2WZUbXuE90o035QsY');

/**
 * Parameters: message-literal, registrationIds-array, No. of retries, callback-function
 */
sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: You ever figure this out?  I'm having the EXACT same issue.